# Undefined variable of view in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I define a variable in view. But problem is that it shows undefined. My task is, first i take all the input from user using form helper then i want to post it to the **store** function & do some calculation and then pass it to the view for showing purpose. But i tried it, unfortunately shows undefined.Undefined variable is "**totalamount"**  Here i attached all the code:

## controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\TestSetup;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class TestRequestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $allTestNames=TestSetup::all()->pluck('test_name','id');
//        $testNames=TestSetup::orderBy('test_name')
//                      ->get();

     return view('testrequestentries.createTestRequestEntry')->withAlltestnames($allTestNames);


//        return view('testrequestentries.createTestRequestEntry');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

//      if(Input::get('Add')) {
          $total=$request->fee+$total;
          return view('testrequestentries.createTestRequestEntry')->withTotalamount($total); 

//      }else if(Input::get('Save')){
//          
//      }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

## view

```
@extends ('main')
@section('title','|Test Request Entry')

@section('stylesheets')
    {!! Html:: style('css/parsley.css')!!}
@endsection  
@section('content')


            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'testrequests.store','data-parsley-validate'=>'']) !!}
                {{Form::label('patient_name','Name of the Patient:')}}
                {{Form::text('patient_name',null,array('class' => 'form-control','required'=>'', 'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Patient Name is required'))}}

                {{Form::label('date_of_birth','Date Of Birth:')}}
                {{Form::date('date_of_birth',null,array('class' => 'form-control','data-parsley-required' =>'true')) }}

                {{Form::label('mobile_no','Mobile No:')}}
                {{Form::text('mobile_no',null,array('class' => 'form-control','type'=> 'number','maxlength'=>'11','minlength' => '11','required'=>'', 'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Mobile No is required'))}}

                {{Form::label('test_id','Select Test:')}}               
                {{Form::select('test_id',$alltestnames,null,['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'','placeholder' => 'Pick a Test...'])}}         

                {{Form::label('fee','Fee:')}}
                {{Form::text('fee',null,array('class' => 'form-control','required'=>'', 'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Fee is required'))}}

                {{Form::submit('Add',array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success','style' => 'margin-top:10px;'))}}


                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>SL</th>
                              <th>Test Name</th>
                              <th>Fee</th>
                              <th>Type Name</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      @php ($i=1)   

                             <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{$i}}</th>
                                <td>{{$totalamount}}</td>


                              </tr>
                            </tbody>  
                            @php ($i++)


                    </table>

{!! Form::close() !!}

    @section('scripts')
        {!! Html:: script('js/parsley.min.js')  !!}
    @endsection
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the view is returned from `create()` here, so change this:

```
return view('testrequestentries.createTestRequestEntry')->withAlltestnames($allTestNames);
```

To:

```
return view('testrequestentries.createTestRequestEntry', [
    'alltestnames' => $allTestNames,
    'totalamount' => $total
]);
```

In the `store()` method, do not return the view. Redirect `back()` or to `index()` or `show()` methods instead.

Comment: @MohammadYakub change it in the store method too. If you get an error, please tell me what the error says.

Comment: i get the total by adding all the fee whose user selected. so task is if user press add button then one fee added with previous. so my idea is that when user press add button then post it in store function  and just show the user "total amount " but error is undefined

Comment: @MohammadYakub so, the original problem is solved, you don't see the `Underfined variable` error? As for the `total` issue, it's not clear and it's not related to the original question, so I recommend you to create a new question and describe what exactly you want to get.

Comment: yes. if i use it in create.. then its ok... but i want to use in store function

Answer (score 0):

first thing first: check the value of `$total=$request->fee+$total;`

ie: put "dd('$total', $total);" right after the line you set it, before the return.

second: make it simplier `return view(...)->with('totalAmount', $total);`

test the value of $totalAmount in the view (BLADE file) 
ie: `{{dump('totalAmount', $totalAmount)}}`

Anyway the store() method does NOT store anything ... WHY THAT?